# Windows Command Screen

Tags: c, codeblocks

Here's an example script of a simple program I wrote in CodeBlocks

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Trollface", "Title", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

That's great and all, it shows a messagebox, but there is a pesky console behind it. How can I remove the console?

Comment: you are using visual studio right?

Comment: When creating the project, which template did you use? I'd answer with how to fix your existing project, but I'm not sure, so for now, recreate your project as a "GUI application" rather than a console application.

Comment: Actually, have a look at this guide (http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project). Find the dialog box which is second picture from the end (http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=File:TargetOptions.png). Change the type drop down to something more apt.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably created a console project.  You can detach from a console using `FreeConsole()`.